# Google Maps tracking my own location isnt working in WebView

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, webview

Hello I'm working on programming a Google Maps WebView. I was trying to track and display my own location. When I press the button, it loads for a while and it said that Google Maps couldn't determine my precise location. I tried running it on Android 5.1 Api 22 Lollipop, it still doesnt work.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.ali.bellsolution;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 0;

    WebView myWebView;

    String mapPath = "https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.5112044,-0.2712415,14z";

    /**
     * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
     */
    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }



    /**
     * WebChromeClient subclass handles UI-related calls
     * Note: think chrome as in decoration, not the Chrome browser
     */
    public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                       GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
            // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        loadPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);


        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());



        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl(mapPath);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Pop the browser back stack or exit the activity
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private void loadPermissions(String perm, int requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, perm)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{perm}, requestCode);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

**Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ali.bellsolution" >



    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="WebViewApp"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="WebViewApp"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image: The Emulator]

Comment: Any success with this?